# Django templates. Any way to nest {{ }} in {% %}?

Tags: python, django, templates

I am working with a Django templates.  I want to pass a variable to my template called **js_files** which is a list of JavaScript files that I want to add to the end of the HTML. For example, here is a sample **js_files** array:

```
js_files = ['fancy_dialog.js', 'animate_everything.js']
```

In my Django template, I would like to be able to do something like this:

```
{% for js_file in js_files %}
<script src="{% static '{{ js_file | safe }}' %}"></script>
{% endfor %}
```

This is what I get:

```
<script src="/static/%7B%7B%20js_file%20%7C%20safe_file%20%7D%7D"></script>
<script src="/static/%7B%7B%20js_file%20%7C%20safe_file%20%7D%7D"></script>
```

This is what I desire:

```
<script src="/static/fancy_dialog.js"></script>
<script src="/static/animate_everything.js"></script>
```

The syntax "{{ js_file | safe }}" does exactly what I want it to.  But I cannot summarily wrap that value with "{% static 'JS-FILE-VARIABLE-HERE' %}".  It doesn't nest.  Anyway to do this?

Comment: Can you not assign `js_file | safe` to some variable and then just interpolate them?

Comment: I could vary easily wrap a for loop around "<script src="{% static 'fancy_dialog.js' %}"></script>" and this would produce the fully qualified reference "<script src="/static/fancy_dialog.js"></script>".  But that isn't what you should do.  Because if "/static/" ever changes, it breaks the reference.  Using "{% static 'fancy_dialog.js' %} ensures that if the static path ever does change, I will still get the correct path.  I'm just trying to see if there is a way I can do {% static ITEM %} where ITEM is a variable.

Comment: `%7B%7B%20` - these are `{`, `{`, ` `. Remove quotation and bracket from within template tag.

Comment: Thanks Ivan.  That's the magic sauce alright.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can of course use template context variables in templatetags (well, those that are written to accept them of course but that's the case for most), you just pass the variable name directly - without quotes, and without the contextvar `{{ }}` syntax. In your case it's just a matter of:

```
{% for js_file in js_files %}
    <script src="{% static js_file %}"></script>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Brilliant.  And emphatically simple.  Been plugging away with Django for about a week now.  I "think" I really like it.  Apologize for the newb questions.  This really helps.  Thank you Bruno!

Answer (score 0):

I can't yet comment, so I'll put this as an answer. Can you use a django engine, to generate the script strings in the view, then pass as a list to the template. Include it as a '|safe' variable.
See [https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/templates/#django.template.loader.engines](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/templates/)

Something like:

```
from django.template import engines

django_engine = engines['django']

js_files = ['fancy_dialog.js', 'animate_everything.js']

html_template = []
for my_js_file in js_files:
    my_template = engines.from_string('{% load static %}<script src="{% static "{0}" %}"></script>'.format(my_js_file))
    html_template.append(my_template.render())
```

Comment: Hopefully Django's template language doesn't require such boilerplate for simple things...

Comment: Thanks @brunodesthuilliers, you've taught me something new.